# Refreshing views in Android HorizontalListView

Tags: android, listview

I am creating a HorizontalListView using the DevSmart library ([GitHub link](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android)). When a user clicks on an element, I am catching the event and want to refresh all the views so I can show the user's selection. I've tried a bunch of different things and just can't get the HorizontalListView to refresh its views:

```
// does not work
mHorizontalListView.invalidate();
mHorizontalListView.requestLayout();

// does not work
mHorizontalListView.notify();

// does not work
mHorizontalListView.notifyAll();

// works, but scrolls to position 0 which isn't desirable
mHorizontalListView.setAdapter(mHorizontalListViewAdapter);
```

Is there any analog to invalidateViews on regular ListViews that I'm missing here. I know my selection update code is working because if I scroll the selected element on and off, when the element shows up again and has to be rebuilt, it shows up properly.

Comment: i don't exact;y get what you are trying to do. Why do you want to invalidate() (or everything else you tried) in the first place to "show the user's selection"? what do you want to achieve? What does "show the user's selection" mean to you? e.g. change background color for this item to represent a selected state?

Comment: Yes, a user clicking on an element of this list view is not taking them anywhere. It's just changing the visible state of the item. If another item was previously selected, that item will no longer be selected, hence why I need to invalidate all the views. I would prefer to not have to keep references to selected list items and manually refresh them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need notifyDataSetChanged() method

Comment: I'm so dumb! My adapter of type ListAdapter so the notifyDataSetChanged() wasn't available. Changing it to a BaseAdapter and calling this method did the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: I used notifyDataSetChanged() in  listview.setOnItemClickListener but If I put this one background is not changing so where I will put this. Also please see my [**Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538993/how-to-change-backgroung-color-when-click-on-horizontal-listview-items-in-androi)